# VBA Search Column D for "PM" then Add 12 hours to Column B if Found

Tags: vba, excel

I have an unfortunately specific question and my ability to google/piece together VBA codes can only go so far.

I'm importing a report from a text file that has columns showing 30 minute intervals (see screenshot). For some reason, any time after 12PM will show as AM in column B but not in column D. I'm trying to create a code that will search column D for PM and add 12 hours to column B so it ends up as PM. My attempt isn't working and I believe it's because of the ranges.

[Screenshot of Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkRka.png)

```
Sub AM2PM()    
Dim rngC As Range
Dim rngT As Range
Set rngT = Range("B2", Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))

rngT.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM"

For Each rngC In rngT
    If InStr(1, (Range("D")), "PM") > 0 Then
        rngC.Value = DateValue(rngC.Value) + TimeValue(rngC.Value) + 0.5
    Else
        rngC.Value = DateValue(rngC.Value) + TimeValue(rngC.Value)
    End If
Next rngC

End Sub
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Its not working because `12:00 - 12:30 PM` is **not a date type object**. It's a string. You'll need to strip out the `12:30 PM` for instance from the cell first.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman What would be the best way to go about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try without looping:

```
Sub Minus30M()
    With Columns("D:D")
        .Replace What:="A", Replacement:=" A", LookAt:=xlPart
        .Replace What:="P", Replacement:=" P", LookAt:=xlPart
    End With
    Range("D1").FormulaR1C1 = "=1/48"
    Columns("D:D").Copy
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("D1").Copy
    Columns("B:B").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlSubtract
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much! Would you mind explaining how you thought of it? Would love to understand so I can improve.